CORS issue with Nginx and NodeJS in Docker Compose
I try to create a docker compose running a React App with Nginx and NodeJS, I can see my home page in react but I get the following error:

cross-origin request blocked: Same-origin policy does not allow reading from remote resources at http://backend:3000/message. (Reason: Unsuccessful CORS request).

This is how I call the API from React:
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://backend:3000/message')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => setMessage(data))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error al obtener el mensaje:', error));
  }, []); 


This is my Dockerfile for NodeJS:
FROM node:20-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]

This is my Dockerfile for React:
FROM node:20.11.1-alpine3.19 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.25.4-alpine3.18
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

This is how I created my conf.d:
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Content-Type';
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}


And this is my docker-compose.yaml:
version: '3'

services: 

  backend:
    image: pedrocastro2001/back-end-node
    container_name: backend
    networks: 
      - node-network
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"

  frontend:
    image: pedrocastro2001/front-end-react
    container_name: frontend
    networks: 
      - node-network
    ports: 
      - "5173:80"
  
networks: 
  node-network:
    driver: bridge

I can't figure out what's wrong with my configuration, I'd be very grateful for any help.

React runs in the browser on your host. The address to use is http://localhost:3000/message

Does this answer your question? Fail to resolve docker compose service name from front end

Assuming your backend is Express, see this answer for enabling CORS support. It's not required at all in your frontend nginx config

@Phil Thank you!!! The solution was to use the address http://localhost:3000/message

Also see "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend.  One of my solutions there is to put everything behind the same reverse proxy, at which point you can use a path-only URL to call the backend, and there is no longer a cross-origin call.

If you want to serve your React frontend through Nginx and docker, you need to add an Nginx service to your docker-compose.yml file.
version: '3'

services: 

  backend:
    image: pedrocastro2001/back-end-node
    container_name: backend
    networks: 
      - node-network
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"

  frontend:
    image: pedrocastro2001/front-end-react
    container_name: frontend
    networks: 
      - node-network
    ports: 
      - "5173:80"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx-c
    networks:
      - node-network
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d  # Mount your nginx configuration
    depends_on:
      - frontend

networks: 
  node-network:
    driver: bridge

Have you done something different to configure your Nginx, is it working?
